# Forwarding all Internet Traffic over VPN (PPTP UFW)

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, ufw

I've set up a VPN using the guide [here](http://silverlinux.blogspot.se/2012/05/how-to-pptp-vpn-on-ubuntu-1204-pptpd.html) but what I cannot seem to get working is forwarding all my internet traffic over the VPN. I can connect and view the other machines on my network.

I am using UFW to set the firewall settings. I have opened 22, 1723, 80 so far.

Output of route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
REMOTEIP  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `route -n` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect all traffic to VPN, then do

```
 sudo route del default
 sudo route add default dev ppp0
```

You can also set it up in ppp config by adding option `replacedefaultroute`

Comment: That broke it, when I entered that it said: SIOCDELRT: No such process

Comment: @Josh Anyway you need to set defaultroute to ppp0.